# permutation test for a difference in means of an autocorrelated time series over two unequal time periods

Tags: time-series, permutation-test

I'm trying to figure out a way to test for a difference in the means (for instance) over two somewhat unequal periods in an AR(1) time series. For data without any AR structure, I might do something like the example below using a permutation test. But, knowing that the data aren't ~iid, how can I modify my approach? E.g., fit an AR(1) model for each sample and then add it back into each random sample?

````
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
# an ar1 ts with an offset
n <- 120
phi <- 0.5
y <- c(arima.sim(model=list(ar=phi),n=n)) + 10
# add a slight diff for illustration
y[51:120] <- y[51:120] + 0.5
# take a look
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=1:n,y=y),color="grey40") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50,linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=1:50,y = mean(y[1:50]))) +
  geom_line(aes(x=51:120,y = mean(y[51:120]))) +
  theme_minimal()

# time period 1 is observations 1:50, time period 2 is 51:120
sampOne <- y[1:50]
sampTwo <- y[51:120]
# diff in means
testStat <- mean(sampTwo) - mean(sampOne) #0.32

# simple permutation test
m <- 1e3
testStatPermute <- numeric()
for(i in 1:m){
  indexSampOne <- sample(1:n,length(sampOne))
  tmpOne <- y[indexSampOne]
  tmpTwo <- y[-indexSampOne]
  testStatPermute[i] <- mean(tmpTwo) - mean(tmpOne)
}
# take a look
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x=testStatPermute),fill="grey40",alpha=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = testStat,color="grey40",linetype="dashed") +
  labs(y="Density",x="Test Statistic") + theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
# prob
sum(testStatPermute > testStat) / m #0.048
```
````